# Does the property $\forall x\exists y\forall z: x*y*z=e$ hold in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Does the given property hold in a group. If yes, why?

$$\forall x\exists y\forall z
: x*y*z=e; \quad x,y,z\in G$$

It points out:

1. all elements (given by $z$ above) have unique inverse (given by $xy = z^{-1}$ above).
2. Set of inverse of elements of group = set of group elements.
3. Each row has the complete set.

Can use left cancellation to show row elements are unique, as given two entries in group table:
$ab = ac \implies b=c$.

Similarly, for uniqueness of column elements can use right-cancellation. There $ba= ca\implies a=c$.

But, that is not the correct approach, as need to first find reason for #1.

Comment: Be very careful with the order of quantifiers. Here's a tip: any time you have lots of quantifiers, you can think of it as a game. I choose an $x$, you choose a $y$, and I choose a $z$. I'm trying to make $xyz=e$ false. You're trying to make $xyz=e$ true. The statement $\forall x\exists y\forall z:xyz=e$ is true if and only if you have a winning strategy in this game.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger kindly elaborate, if possible with answer.

Comment: If you change it to $\forall x\forall z\exists y$, the game changes to me choosing $x$ and $z$ and then you choosing $y$.

Comment: @azimut I hope have done the needful.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Your response is very (too much) interesting. Kindly provide an answer, then can compare both logic expressions in light of your approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stated property
$$\forall x \exists y\forall z : x*y*z = e$$ is true if and only if $G = \{e\}$ is the trivial group.

Set $x = e$. Then the question is if there is a $y$ with $y*z = e$ for all $z$. Now $z = y^{-1}$ is uniquely determined by $y$, so the property is wrong as soon as $G$ contains $2$ different elements.

**Addition** In the comments, the alternative property
$$\forall x\forall z\exists y: x*y*z = e$$
has been discussed. The crucial difference to the original one is that now $y$ may be specified after $z$ has been fixed, so we can pick $y$ depending on $x$ and $z$ (and not only depending on $x$ as before).
Consequently, the alternative property is softer than the original one. Indeed, it is true for all groups $G$ (setting $y = x^{-1} z^{-1}$).

Comment: But, isn't it true that all elements in a group have unique inverse?

Comment: @jiten sure that is true.

Comment: @jiten, the assertion would say that _every_ $z$ is the inverse of $x*y$. Yes, the inverse of $x*y$ is unique, so there is only _one_ $z$ that will work. Thus, there's only one element in the group.

Comment: Then am not clear, why only holds true for trivial group. Seems by your last comment, that the order of evaluation of logic expression different from left to right? If so, how to modify it to reflect three points stated above?

Comment: @azimut if you are interpreting the logical quanitfiers correctly (which you probably are-- I'm not sure) then you don't need to specify a case for $x$.  If $z_1 \ne z_2$ then $xyz_1 \ne xyz_2$ and thus they can't *both* be equal to $e$.  So this is never true (Unless its the trivial group)

Comment: @fleablood Is there a way to modify the logic expression to reflect the three points?

Comment: The difficlut (and I'll admit it threw me) is the logicals $\forall x \exists y \forall z$.  That means for every $x$ there will be $y$ so that for every $z$ we can have $xyz =e$.  That can't be true.   If there were then $xyz_1 = xyz_2 = e$ for every $z_1, z_2$  But that's not possible if $z_1 \ne z_2$.

Comment: Just sound it out slowly.   For every $x$, there exists a $y$, so that for every $z$ we can have $xyz = e$... azimut's argument seems sound to me.

Comment: @fleablood so it should be changed to $\forall x\exists y \exists z$ instead?

Comment: Maybe.  But I suspect what your really want to say is $\forall x \forall z \exists y$.... which is true:  Just set $y := x^{-1}z^{-1}$ then $xyz = x(x^{-1}z^{-1})z = (xx^{-1})(z^{-1}z)=ee=e$.

Comment: @fleablood Then it means:  for all elements $x$, and for all elements $z$, there is some element $y$, s.t. $x\times y= z^{-1}$. Also, your last comment states $y= x^{-1}z^{-1} \implies yx =z, yz= x$.

Comment: Yes... and that is true.   Just let $y = x^{-1}z^{-1}$ and then $x\times y = x\times (x^{-1}z^{-1}) (xx^{-1})z^{-1}=ez^{-1} = z^{-1}$.

Comment: @fleablood I agree; your comment "$xyz_1=xyz_2 \implies z_1 = z_2$" gives a valid argument without specifying $x=e$.

Comment: @azimut  As a request, please have the alternative expression ($\forall x\forall z \exists y$) in your answer and compare the difference it brings to meaning.

Comment: @jiten which alternative expression are you referring to?

Comment: @azimut kindly see my last comment after edit.

Comment: @azimut Thanks a lot for the edit and the explanation.

Comment: @jiten you are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

(Adapted from a comment)

Be very careful with the order of quantifiers. Here's a tip: any time you have lots of quantifiers, you can think of it as a game.

Take the statement $\forall x\exists y\forall z:xyz=e$. This means: I choose an $x$, you choose a $y$, and I choose a $z$. I'm trying to make $xyz=e$ false. You're trying to make $xyz=e$ true. The statement $\forall x\exists y\forall z:xyz=e$ is true if and only if you have a winning strategy in this game. ("For any move I make, there is a move you can make so that for any move I make, you win.")

Here, assuming $G$ is not the trivial group (it has at least two elements), you do not have a winning strategy in this game: I have the final move and so I can muck it up at the last second. Example: I pick $x=e$, you pick some $y$, I pick $z=y^{-1}g$ where $g\ne e$.

If you change it to $\forall x\forall z\exists y$, the game changes to me choosing $x$ and $z$ and then you choosing $y$. Now, you *do* have a winning strategy because after I choose $x$ and $z$, you can choose $y=x^{-1}z^{-1}$ and win.

$\forall$ means I move. $\exists$ means you move. Changing the order of quantifiers means changing the order of who moves in the game.

Comment: Excellent, but seems not read before this interesting interpretation of $\forall, \exists$.

Comment: @jiten You may not see this explanation in a typical textbook, but I also use it as a visualization tool. It works in reverse, too: games can be explained with logical quantifiers, and that's something you might seen in textbooks that deal with games.